# C# - passing class reference to a C# DLL, and then accessing it

Tags: c#, dll

I'm wondering if I am allowed to pass value reference of class that loaded the DLL to the DLL and then access the class through that value saved. I have not found any sources ever mentioning or any examples showing such. I do imagine you would traditionally rather call upon a function(s) inside the DLL, and return values, but I am working on a game server and want to have DLL's have access to document classes, especially the main program class, and directly modify numbers needed. For as3 I can do this example down below.

```cs
class = new _Class(MovieClip(this)); //passes current class value `ref`
```

And then inside `_Class`, you save it like such

```cs
           public var saveValueRefOfClass:MovieClip;

            public function Entity(val:MovieClip)
            {
                this.saveValueRefOfClass = val; //save it
            }
```

and then access the value ref inside the _Class like so;

```cs
    saveValueRefOfClass.anyFunc(); //call back to that class
```

Comment: Either use only `static`members in your class - which mmeans there is no instance of your program-class - or create an **instance** and call its members.

Comment: Considering the code snippets you showed as just pseudo-c#-code, what is wrong with that? I don't get how what you showed in the code snippets doesn't do what you want.

Comment: If the `dll` is a .net managed one this will happen as if you were declaring and instantiating inside the .exe. Could you explain in other works what you want?

Comment: @dedecos I simply want to save value reference of class that loaded the DLL, so I can access that class that loaded the DLL at any time I want from inside of the DLL. Yes this is a .net DLL. By accessing I mean any function/variable inside the parent class that loaded DLL.

Comment: Some things are unclear to me, please clarify what you meant by "save a value reference" (you meant to save a reference?) and "access that class that loaded the dll" (you meant access an object that was instantiated in the dll?).

Comment: @dedecos Yes, save it as a reference, but they do say that reference and value ref is a bit different. So while yes you instantiated the DLL, it is the class it was instantiated in that I want to access from the DLL (its functions,vars ,etc).

Comment: @Thehunch buddy what you mean by "instantiate a dll"? DLL's don't get instantiated. They are loaded automatically to the process in the process startup. At c# code-level, a class declared in a c# dll can be treated as just another class declared inside your .exe code. Regarding a "value ref" I don't have any idea on what it should be - can you please share a link explaining what is it?

Comment: @dedecos I see. Can you show an example then on how one could access for example Program.cs from the Dll. I may be over complicating everything from ignorance. From what I get, the function inside DLL can access any function on my program, I suppose that is what I don't know how to do, and was assuming you needed to pass references to it.

Comment: Okay, so you want to, let's say, declare a class inside the .exe project code and call it from a dll code? Can you explain why would you want to do that? Why not accessing a *dll code* from the *main executable code*?

Comment: I mentioned it in the question, I am doing a fast pace game server and want DLL to update certain information at a time for every users. For example skill debuffs/buffs. Sending these changes to a DLL vs DLL accessing the list holding the values that change every few seconds is one of a few desirables. Not the only thing, but because of how complex the combat can get, I'd prefer the dll to be able to access many things on its own and act as a brain. Yes I do need DLL to keep dynamic flow of unique classes/combat etc without having to store hundredths of classes in the project.

Comment: If you want the DLL to update this list, why don't you just declare the list in the DLL project and make it access directly this list? This way your dll will be able to read/modify this list as well as your main .exe project.

Comment: *"Yes I do need DLL to keep dynamic flow of unique classes/combat etc without having to store hundredths of classes in the project."* can you explain why you need the dll to not "store" hundreds of classes?

Comment: Its about organizing. The DLL's are the pvp classes. The user class holds the list for each user. I mean the main project to have hundredths of classes, not the DLL. You don't want to recompile the server to make small fixes to the classes, instead you can simply update the DLL that the server loads in. I hope this makes a lot more common sense, you don't want to keep nothing but the server in your server code, rest that can be dynamic, let it be dynamic such as DLL's.

Comment: @Thehunch and where do you suggest these "hundreds of classes" to be declared? They need to be declared somewhere.

Comment: The usual way to organize this is dividing the whole application in layers. You can have 1 or more DLLs representing each one of these layers where every structural code is declared inside these DLLs and the main .exe is only the entry point of the application - the real magic actually should happen inside these DLLS, not the opposite.

Comment: the path to every DLL is stored in DB, so if a user wants a specific combat class, they load the DLL that holds the logic for the combat class.

Comment: Well... Okay then...

Comment: @dedecos I suspected that one should do everything inside the DLL that is needed to process logic, this is good clarification because non of the sources ever specify if you can or even should venture out.

Comment: I think you are missing some basic concepts here bud, however I created an answer teaching you how to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides **strongly** recommending against this approach in comments, you can do this by simply including the main .exe dependency to your DLL project.

In the solution explorer, just *right-click in the DLL project -> Add -> Reference* and select the executable project name in the tab *Projects*.

This will expose all public names declared in the executable project to your DLL project.

Comment: Interesting. Would anything similar be possible if you load the DLL from a path? dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(filePath);

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I can't think why you couldn't do that.

Comment: I see, so you can use references of class you pass into DLL to access it? I suppose now that I know, I should change my approach, i'll reconsider it, but it is nice to know we could if it was really necessary which I guess isn't.

Comment: Yes bud, but as I said I think you are missing some basic concepts here. As a better solution for your application could be abstract the types that are common between the .exe and the .dlls into `interface`s. And of course, removing all the inner logic of your application from the .exe. As I said in the comments of your question, in these kind of applications the .exe should be considered as just an entry point of your code. The *central* piece of code that will tie all dlls together, but the all other code should be moved to libraries.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions the information means everything.

Comment: See: your .exe doesn't have to know exactly what is going on inside a method if that method is not declared in the assembly of your .exe. Imagine you have a common class like the `CPlayer` class (representing basic behavior for each player of your game). All the public behavior of this class (such as `Attack`ing other players, activate a skill, etc) should be abstracted into an `interface` (which CPlayer will implement) and isolate this interface declaration inside a specific assembly (i.e. you should have a specific DLL for this).

Comment: ... That way *every* piece of code in your application that actually needs to know *what* the class CPlayer do, can be done by just referencing the interfaces that CPlayer implements. I suggest you to spend some time reading about POO, abstraction and polymorphism before diving into a complex project such as a game server.